# Why doesn't PlotRange seem to work with ChromaticityPlot?

Tags: plotting, color

By default, Mathematica usually adds a little extra axes lengths in plots (in this case, for x<0 and y<0):

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Which we can of course fix using `PlotRange`:

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 25}}]
```

[image]

Now I want to do the same with `ChromaticityPlot`, which by default has some strange axes range:

```
ChromaticityPlot[{}]
```

[image]

However, even though [PlotRange is an option for ChromaticityPlot,](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChromaticityPlot.html) using it doesn't seem to totally work:

```
ChromaticityPlot[{}, PlotRange -> {{0, .8}, {0, .85}}]
```

[image]

I say 'totally' because it *does* change the upper bounds of the axes, but it doesn't make the origin where the axes meet. In fact, actually, if you look closely, it adds a little extra to the upper bound of the axes too, even if it changes them.

Am I missing something simple? How can I do this?

Comment: Set `PlotRangePadding->None`. You'll see similar behavior in your first plot if you set `Frame->True`.

Comment: @N.J.Evans, ah, of course... I missed that it takes all Graphics options. So this happens here because ChromaticityPlot automatically has a Frame? If you make this an answer, I'll select it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ChromaticityPlot` uses a frame rather than an axis, so you'll need to set the option `PlotRangePadding->None`.

Additionally, setting `Frame-False,Axes->True` is not enough, to get rid of the extra little bit of axis you see, so `PlotRangePadding` has to be explicitly mentioned in this case.

```
ChromaticityPlot[
 {}
 , PlotRange -> {{0.1, 0.5}, {0.1, 0.5}}
 , Frame -> False
 , Axes -> True
 ]
```

[image]

vs.

```
ChromaticityPlot[
     {}
     , PlotRange -> {{0.1, 0.5}, {0.1, 0.5}}
     , Frame -> False
     , Axes -> True
     , PlotRangePadding->None
     ]
```

[image]